# Uncaught ReferenceError: onOpenCvReady is not defined

Tags: javascript, opencv

I tried [openCVjs tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html) in my local and everytime I load it I get error on console

What I have tried ?

1. Loading without a file server, because the openCV.js library is around 11mb. So thought that could be an issue.
2. Loaded with simpleHTTPserver using python even then I got the same error. Attached below screenshot of the network requests.

Please note that test.js resides in the same path as that of openCV.js but test.js works because I tried console.log from it.

Answer (score 3):

You should load opencv.js asynchronously.
Add this into your index.html

```
<script>
  function onOpenCvReady() {
    console.log( 'OpenCV Ready', cv);
  }
</script>
<script async src="opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady();" type="text/javascript">    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it only works when the `onOpenCvReady()` function is declarated in an HTML page.
When the function is loaded from an external `test.js file`, I have to refresh the index page two times, then it suddenly works without any errors.

I embedded it into my HTML page like this:

```
<p id="status">OpenCV.js is loading...</p>

<!-- <script async src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

<script async src="js/opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady();" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function onOpenCvReady() {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'OpenCV.js is ready.';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Yunnosch putting the function into html file instead of js file is also a solution, but i admit it, it is the worst solution. Even tho it is a solution

Comment: I never thought non-answer hunters is a thing, Lol. Thanks for the warning, i will be more careful next time @Yunnosch